# Generate a matrix of N X N in specific pattern

Tags: algorithm, matrix

I wanted to generate a N X N matrix in a specified order as given below.
If N=3

```
1  2  5
4  3  6
9  8  7
```

If N=4

```
   1   2   5   10
   4   3   6   11
   9   8   7   12
  16  15  14   13
```

Can anyone help me to device the algorithm for generating the matrix in the same pattern

Comment: Asking for help strongly suggests that you have made some (possibly serious) effort and got stuck.  There's no evidence that you have done anything more than asked for someone to do your work for you.  SO isn't really here for that.

Comment: Can u add programming language tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way,

```js
function f(N){
  // Initialise the matrix
  const m = new Array(N);
  for (let i=0; i<N; i++)
    m[i] = new Array(N);

  // Initialise starting positions,
  // diagonal, and counter.
  let i = 0;
  let j = 0;
  let d = 0;
  let c = 1;
  
  while (d < N){
    // Iterate down
    for (; i<=d; i++){
      m[i][j] = c;
      c = c + 1;
    }
    i = i - 1;
    j = j - 1;
    // Iterate left
    for (; j>=0; j--){
      m[i][j] = c;
      c = c + 1;
    }
    i = 0;
    d = d + 1;
    j = d;
  }
  
  return m;
}

for (let row of f(5))
  console.log(JSON.stringify(row));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can see a pattern here for:

- First row - Differences between number have a series of 1,3,5,7,9....
- First column - Differences between number have a series of 3,5,7,9....
- Diagonals - Differences between number have a series of 2,4,6,8. For each next diagonal, we start from the next difference number of 4,6,8 etc.

For N = 4, first row and column looks like,

```
    1      3      5 
  1 ---- 2 ---- 5 ---- 10
3 |
  |
  4
5 |
  |
  9
7 |
  |
 16
```

Now, let's go with upper half of diagonals starting from main half diagonal

```
  1     2     5     10

      \2    \4   \6
                  \
  4     3     6     11
           \4    \6
            \     \
  9           7     12
                \6
                 \
 16                 13
```

Same goes for lower half of the diagonals.

**Snippet:**

```
private static void fill(int[][] mat){
    int N = mat.length;
    mat[0][0] = 1;
    // fill first row
    for(int i = 1,diff = 1;i < N;++i,diff += 2) mat[0][i] += diff + mat[0][i-1];
    // fill first column
    for(int i = 1,diff = 3;i < N;++i,diff += 2) mat[i][0] += diff + mat[i-1][0];
    // fill diagonally(upper-half)        
    for(int i = 0;i < N;++i){
        int x = 0 , y = i,diff = (i + 1) << 1;
        while(++x < N && ++y < N){
            mat[x][y] = mat[x-1][y-1] + diff;
            diff += 2;
        }
    }
    // fill diagonally(lower-half) 
    for(int i = 1;i < N;++i){
        int x = i , y = 0,diff = (i + 1) << 1;
        while(++x < N && ++y < N){
            mat[x][y] = mat[x-1][y-1] + diff;
            diff += 2;
        }
    }
}
```

**Demo:** https://ideone.com/itOHz2